# Webpack 4 optimization runtimechunk, runtime.js cannot named with chunkhash?

Tags: webpack-4

First: *webpack.config*

```
mode: 'development',
name: 'dev',
target: 'web',
entry: {
    'app': [
        'webpack/hot/dev-server',
        APP_DIR + '/client/app.tsx'
    ]
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/'
},
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            vendors: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: 'vendor',
                priority: -20,
                chunks: 'all'
            }
        }
    }
},
```

The stdout is below, runtime.js has no hashcode on name.

[image: runtime.js has no hashcode]

Second: When I change the output as below:

```
output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/'
},
```

I get this results:

[image]

How could I hashcode named the runtime.js file like other chunk file??